# unable to run flutter app on real device using vs code

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

for the first time using flutter on vs code, I tried running the app on my mobile without an emulator so after enabling the USB debugger and connecting the device. clicking the start debugging icon won't display the app on the screen except for an error in the console.

> Launching lib\main.dart on SM G935F in debug mode... lib\main.dart:1
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file
>   'D:\flutterproj\vstest\flutter_application_1\android\settings.gradle'
>   (C:\Users\abdal.gradle\caches\6.7\scripts\1fnwrr8g4rohfp291nvlxj5qe).
>
> > BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '*BuildScript*' Unsupported class file major version 60
>
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 1m 13s Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed
> with exit code 1 Exited (sigterm)

Just to let you know I already have the flutter SDK downloaded as well as the other things.
and the code has no error it's the same as when you open the flutter app for the first time
please tell me if you need more info.
thanks